# ABC.js does not render on mobile

Tags: bug, abcjs

When viewing answers that use ABC.js, the notation does not render, and I only see a code block with the plaintext ABC.js code. The notation renders correctly only when I view the edit history of the post.

I've experienced this using Android 8 with Chrome version 88

Comment: Also on iOS 14.4, both on the website and via the SE App.